# How to DON'T return string in quotes

Tags: string, list, return, quotes

I have list:

```
itemid = ['113222408782', '113223652945', '113222268092', '113223761722', '113222277037', '113223676589', '113214024190', '113227956444', '113222400375', '113222383960', '113223749386', '113213898511', '113223653433', '113214060057', '113212059543', '113223647852', '113212403974', '113222230789', '113212110156', '113213917508', '113223748917', '113212088893', '113213936773', '113212282559', '113222369037', '113223645004', '113214034011', '113223647208', '113222397481', '113212052765', '113212136602', '113212037895', '113222210185', '113223752305', '113212049744', '113212400978', '113212274566', '113218830085', '113203034623', '113222199167', '113223648988', '113223646543', '113223651519', '113222200831', '113213996789', '113214000484', '113213890605', '113222232853', '113222298617', '113223753658', '113222238111', '113194336951', '113223631876', '113222242464', '113212123303', '113222215450', '113214000567', '113223642160', '113223639750', '113214060070', '113223644511', '113194332243', '113212139900', '113222207007', '113222374260', '113223719876', '113194339799', '113223677943', '113212417158', '113212433693', '113227977319', '113223607151', '113212409228', '113215809743', '113214051350']
```

This list contains 75 values. I'm cutting this list for 20 items list using following method:

```
while len(itemid) > 0:
slice = itertools.islice(itemid, 20)
ha = []
for x in slice:
    ha.append(format(x))
    var1 = ','.join(ha)
```

var1 returns string with 20 values like this:

```
113222408782,113223652945,113222268092,113223761722,113222277037,113223676589,113214024190,113227956444,113222400375,113222383960,113223749386,113213898511,113223653433,113214060057,113212059543,113223647852,113212403974,113222230789,113212110156,113213917508
```

And then I got stuck:

I'm using it for eBay api and I want to do the following command:

```
api_request = {'ItemID': var1}
```

and it returns:

```
{'ItemID': '113223748917,113212088893,113213936773,113212282559,113222369037,113223645004,113214034011,113223647208,113222397481,113212052765,113212136602,113212037895,113222210185,113223752305,113212049744,113212400978,113212274566,113218830085,113203034623,113222199167'}
```

But I need to return the string var1 without quotes like this:

```
{'ItemID': 113223748917,113212088893,113213936773,113212282559,113222369037,113223645004,113214034011,113223647208,113222397481,113212052765,113212136602,113212037895,113222210185,113223752305,113212049744,113212400978,113212274566,113218830085,113203034623,113222199167}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `{'ItemID': 1,2,3}` is invalid format. `{'ItemID': [1,2,3]}` is valid. If you want 1,2,3 as string instead than as array, then `{'ItemID': '1,2,3'}` is what you want.

Comment: Right, I need this format **{'ItemID': [1,2,3]}**. But if I use **{'ItemID': [var1]}**, it will return  **{'ItemID': ['1,2,3']}** still with quotes. And I'm just trying to find the way to get this quotes away

Comment: Can you clarify why you want to remove the quotes

Answer (score 1):

The quotes are not actually part of the string, they just signify that it is a string. Therefore you cannot remove them

Comment: Is there any was to convert this string into something so it won't signify that it is a string and won't print this quotes?

Comment: Maks you can't because it's a string. It signifies it is a string. You can't make a string not a string I don't know how I can make this any simpler. You just don't. It's a visual representation

Answer (score 0):

You does not need to convert array to string, you have to pass the entire object like this:

```
var1 = itertools.islice(itemid, 20)
api_request = {'ItemID': var1}
```

Why are you trying to cast it to a format if you need to pass it as a array?

Regards,
Igor Quirino